# Android Response Timeout

Tags: android, https, httpwebrequest, httprequest

Hi my application requesting some data from server , application shows Dialog to the user till application receives result but in some cases application doesn't receive any response and no timeout occurs and dialog remains forever on the screen.

Following below is code for HttpClient.

```
    HttpParams params = new BasicHttpParams();
    HttpProtocolParams.setVersion(params, HttpVersion.HTTP_1_1);  
    HttpProtocolParams.setContentCharset(params, HTTP.UTF_8);  
    HttpProtocolParams.setUseExpectContinue(params, true);  
     // Turn off stale checking. Our connections break all the time anyway,
    // and it's not worth it to pay the penalty of checking every time.
    HttpConnectionParams.setStaleCheckingEnabled(params, false);

    // Default connection and socket timeout of 30 seconds. Tweak to taste.
    HttpConnectionParams.setConnectionTimeout(params, 5*1000);
    HttpConnectionParams.setSoTimeout(params, 30*1000);
    HttpConnectionParams.setSocketBufferSize(params, 8192);

    ConnManagerParams.setTimeout(params, 5 * 1000);
    ConnManagerParams.setMaxConnectionsPerRoute(params, new ConnPerRouteBean(50));
    ConnManagerParams.setMaxTotalConnections(params, 200);

    // Sets up the http part of the service.
    final SchemeRegistry supportedSchemes = new SchemeRegistry();

    // Register the "http" protocol scheme, it is required
    // by the default operator to look up socket factories.
    final SocketFactory sf = PlainSocketFactory.getSocketFactory();
    supportedSchemes.register(new Scheme("http", sf, 80));
    supportedSchemes.register(new Scheme("https", SSLSocketFactory.getSocketFactory(), 443));  
    final ThreadSafeClientConnManager ccm = new ThreadSafeClientConnManager(params,
            supportedSchemes);

    DefaultHttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient(ccm, params);`
```

please specify the error or some other code suggestions if something is wrong in it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

advice:

when the dialog show, need send delay message to handler, when receive the delay message, dismiss the dialog and cancel request

`Hanlder.sendEmptyMessageDelayed(what,delay_time)`

`HttpUriRequest.abort` to cancel request

the delay time you can assume the timeout or whatever you think the longest time.

Comment: thanks for your response but i'm using Asynchronous tasks for sending the data.could you suggest me some other way to do the same.

Comment: well, the `sendEmptyMessageDelayed` invoke before the task start, you also can do it in anywhere, so if you want to do in your async task, just pass a hanlder reference.

Comment: could you encourage it by providing some examples or explaining it in more detail.

Answer (score 1):

Seems like you are making it too complicated to get TimeOut done. Try doing it as below:

```
//TimeOut is set to 20 seconds
HttpParams httpParams = new BasicHttpParams();
HttpConnectionParams.setConnectionTimeout(httpParams, 20000);
HttpConnectionParams.setSoTimeout(httpParams, 20000);
HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient(httpParams);
```

Comment: thanks for your response earlier i have used the same but didn't work.

Answer (score 0):

I faced same issue in one of my project.

```
HttpConnectionParams.setConnectionTimeout(httpParams, 20000);
HttpConnectionParams.setSoTimeout(httpParams, 20000);
```

but i dont know why above code snipper was not working on random occasions.Timeout used to happen but
not in 20 seconds in my case.

So i came up with little hacky approach.I know its not recommended.but you may find it useful.
you will have 3 scenarios where you will dismiss dialog.and move on.

1) dismiss dialog as soon as you receive response.

2) dismiss dialog if timeout occurs

3) Write a logic for dismissing the dialog in handler.post dealyed.make sure you always mention delay as what you have given in `setSoTimeout` (Not recommended but useful)

So in worst case if you dont receive response/timeout in mentioned timeout duration.
third approach will always work.

Hope this help.

Comment: thanks for your response i have not used handlers i'm using AsynTasks throughout the application with callback Listeners. my callback listeners are not notifying to the Activity.suggest me some other way.